# Catching exception when read_csv in chunks pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I read a csv file while catching an exception (in this case: UnicodeDecodeError) as follows:

```
def read_csv(filename, chunksize=None, iterator=False):
    """Read a csv using pandas, while breaking the file into chunks if necessary"""
    try:
        return pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize, iterator=iterator)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return pd.read_csv(filename, encoding="ISO-8859-1", chunksize=chunksize, iterator=iterator)
```

This works fine when I read the csv not in chunks.

However, when I set the chunksize to a numeric value then it seems to fail in the step when it starts iterating:

```
df = read_csv(filename, chunksize=CHUNKSIZE, iterator=True)

chunk_iter = 0
for chunk in df:   # exception triggered here
    chunk_iter = chunk_iter + 1
```

What can I do to catch an exception in the for loop?

Comment: What exception are you getting? can you show the output? Also, this code snippet, is that from `pd.read_csv()`?

Comment: The exception handling is defined in the function read_csv, which is indeed inside using pd.read_csv(..)

Comment: right. can you post the exception and the output when you try to run this?

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError raised is what's stated. An example from my end:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 9: invalid continuation byte`